# Azure SQL DB causing connection time out for stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

We have hosted our database in Azure and are running stored procedures on this DB. The stored procedures had been running fine till last week but suddenly started giving error connection timeout.

Our database size is **14 GB** and the stored procedures in general return **2k to 20k** records and we are using the **S3 pricing tier (50 DTU)** of Azure DB.

What I found interesting was the first time the stored procedure is executed, it takes a lot of time 2 - 3 mins and this is causing the timeout. The later executions are fast (maybe it caches the execution plan).

Also when I run on the same DB with the same number of records on a machine with the config of 8gb ram, Win10 it runs in **15 seconds**.

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PRSP]   
    @CompanyID INT, 
    @fromDate DATETIME, 
    @toDate DATETIME, 
    @ListMailboxId as MailboxIds Readonly, 
    @ListConversationType as ConversationTypes Readonly
AS
BEGIN       
    SET NOCOUNT ON;    

    SELECT 
        C.ID,
        C.MailboxID,
        C.Status,
        C.CustomerID,
        Cust.FName,
        Cust.LName,
        C.ArrivalDate as ConversationArrivalDate,
        C.[ClosureDate],
        C.[ConversationType],
        M.[From],
        M.ArrivalDate as MessageArrivalDate,
        M.ID as MessageID
    FROM  
        [Conversation] as C
    INNER JOIN
        [ConversationHistory] AS CHis ON (CHis.ConversationID  = C.ID)
    INNER JOIN
        [Message] AS M ON (M.ConversationID = C.ID)
    INNER JOIN
        [Mailbox] AS Mb ON (Mb.ID = C.MailboxID)
    INNER JOIN
        [Customer] AS Cust ON (Cust.ID = C.CustomerID)
    JOIN
        @ListConversationType AS convType ON convType.ID = C.[ConversationType]
    JOIN
        @ListMailboxId AS mailboxIds ON mailboxIds.ID = Mb.ID
    WHERE
        Mb.CompanyID = @CompanyID
        AND ((CHis.CreatedOn > @fromDate
             AND CHis.CreatedOn < @toDate
             AND CHis.Activity = 1
             AND CHis.TagData = '3')
         OR (M.ArrivalDate > @fromDate
             AND M.ArrivalDate < @toDate)) 
END
```

This is the execution plan :

[Execution Plan](https://ufile.io/8b9ym)

Please do give your suggestions as to what improvement is needed? Also do we need to upgrade my pricing tier?

Ideally for a 14GB DB what should be the Azure Pricing tier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That query should take 1 to 3 seconds to complete on your Windows 10 8Gb RAM machine. It takes 15 seconds because SQL Server choose a poor execution plan. In this case, the root cause of poor execution plan is bad estimates, several operators in the plan show big difference between estimated rows and actual rows. For example, SQL Server estimated it only need to perform one seek into pk_customer clustered index, but it performed 16,522 seeks. The same thing occurs with [ConversationHistory].[IX_ConversationID_CreatedOn_Activity_ByWhom] and with [Message].[IX_ConversationID_ID_ArrivalDt_From_RStatus_Type.

Here you have some hints you could follow to improve the performance of the query:

- Update statistics
- Try `OPTION (HASH JOIN)` at the end of the query. It might improve the
  performance or it might slow it down, it even can cause the query to
  error.
- Store table variable data in temporal tables and use them in the query. (`SELECT * INTO #temp_table FROM @table_variable`). Table variables don't have statistics causing bad estimates.
- Identify the first operator where the difference between estimated rows and actual rows are big enough. Split the query. Query1: `SELECT * INTO #operator_result FROM  (query equivalent to operator)`. Query2: write the query using `#operator_result`. Because `#operator_result` is a temporal table SQL Server is forced to reevaluate estimates. In this case, the offending operator is the hash match (inner join)

There are other things you can do to improve the performance of this query:

- Avoid key lookups. There are 16,522 key lookups into `Conversation.PK_dbo.Conversation` clusterd index. It can ve avoided by creating the appropriate covering index. In this case, the covering index is the following:

`DROP INDEX [IX_MailboxID] ON [dbo].[Conversation]
GO
CREATE INDEX IX_MailboxID ON [dbo].[Conversation](MailboxID)
INCLUDE (ArrivalDate, Status, ClosureDate, CustomerID, ConversationType)`

- Split OR predicate into `UNION` or `UNION ALL`. For example:

instead of:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE <predicate1> OR <predicate2>
```

use:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE <predicate1>
UNION
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE <predicate2>
```

Sometimes it improves performance.

Apply each hint individually and measure performance.

EDIT: You can try the following and see if it improves performance:

```
SELECT 
        C.ID,
        C.MailboxID,
        C.Status,
        C.CustomerID,
        Cust.FName,
        Cust.LName,
        C.ArrivalDate as ConversationArrivalDate,
        C.[ClosureDate],
        C.[ConversationType],
        M.[From],
        M.ArrivalDate as MessageArrivalDate,
        M.ID as MessageID
    FROM  
        @ListConversationType AS convType
        INNER JOIN (
            @ListMailboxId AS mailboxIds
            INNER JOIN
                [Mailbox] AS Mb ON (Mb.ID = mailboxIds.MailboxID)
            INNER JOIN
                [Conversation] as C
                ON C.ID = Mb.ID
        ) ON convType.ID = C.[ConversationType]
        INNER HASH JOIN
            [Customer] AS Cust ON (Cust.ID = C.CustomerID)
        INNER HASH JOIN
            [ConversationHistory] AS CHis ON (CHis.ConversationID  = C.ID)
        INNER HASH JOIN
            [Message] AS M ON (M.ConversationID = C.ID)

    WHERE
        Mb.CompanyID =  @CompanyID
        AND ((CHis.CreatedOn > @fromDate
             AND CHis.CreatedOn < @toDate
             AND CHis.Activity = 1
             AND CHis.TagData = '3')
         OR (M.ArrivalDate > @fromDate
             AND M.ArrivalDate < @toDate))
```

And this:

```
SELECT 
    C.ID,
    C.MailboxID,
    C.Status,
    C.CustomerID,
    Cust.FName,
    Cust.LName,
    C.ArrivalDate as ConversationArrivalDate,
    C.[ClosureDate],
    C.[ConversationType],
    M.[From],
    M.ArrivalDate as MessageArrivalDate,
    M.ID as MessageID
FROM  
    @ListConversationType AS convType
    INNER JOIN (
        @ListMailboxId AS mailboxIds
        INNER JOIN
            [Mailbox] AS Mb ON (Mb.ID = mailboxIds.MailboxID)
        INNER JOIN
            [Conversation] as C
            ON C.ID = Mb.ID
    ) ON convType.ID = C.[ConversationType]
    INNER MERGE JOIN
        [Customer] AS Cust ON (Cust.ID = C.CustomerID)
    INNER MERGE JOIN
        [ConversationHistory] AS CHis ON (CHis.ConversationID  = C.ID)
    INNER MERGE JOIN
        [Message] AS M ON (M.ConversationID = C.ID)

WHERE
    Mb.CompanyID =  @CompanyID
    AND ((CHis.CreatedOn > @fromDate
         AND CHis.CreatedOn < @toDate
         AND CHis.Activity = 1
         AND CHis.TagData = '3')
     OR (M.ArrivalDate > @fromDate
         AND M.ArrivalDate < @toDate))
```

Comment: Can you help me here? I wrote a covering index as you suggested _Avoid key lookups. There are 16,522 key lookups into Conversation.PK_dbo.Conversation clusterd index. It can ve avoided by creating the appropriate coverage index._ But there is no change in the time, still taking 15 sec on local machine. Here is the index that I wrote hope I am going in the correct direction here. `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_CONVID ON [Conversation] (ID) 
INCLUDE (ArrivalDate,[Status], ClosureDate, CustomerID, ConversationType)`

Comment: @Saurabh, The execution plan is still showing key lookups?

Comment: @Saurabh, I edited my answer to include the covering index.

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick responses. I created this index. `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Conv_MailboID_ConvType_CustID] ON [dbo].[Conversation]
(
 [MailboxID] ASC,
 [ConversationType] ASC,
 [CustomerID] ASC
)
INCLUDE (  [Status],
 [ArrivalDate],
 [ClosureDate])` And now on local it runs in 1 sec. I have included all those fields on which I do a 'where' in the index and the fields which I use in 'select' are included in the 'include' section as a covering.

Comment: @Saurabh glad to hear that!. Could you please show the new execution plan. I'm curious about that  :-)

Comment: Sure. [link](https://ufile.io/p67se) This is the new execution plan. It takes 15 sec on the Azure SQL DB and 1 sec on Local Machine.

Comment: @Saurabh. Still lots of seeks. I think it can be improved further. May I ask how many customers there are in the database? and messages, and message history rows? It's difficult to optimize a query without sitting in front of the database.

Comment: There are 29227 in records in the Customer table. 168120 records in Message table and 51981 records in ConversationHistory table. What improvements can be done?

Comment: @Saurabh, I was thinking on forcing some hash match inner join, but I'm afraid those numbers are too big.

Comment: @Saurabh. Please, give me some time to rewrite the query forcing some hash match joins and merge joins. I think it worth trying, but It might or might  not improve the performance.

Comment: @Saurabh, I edited my answer. Could you please try it and see if it improves performance? It even can fail. If that occurs, try removing one HASH or MERGE at a time and try again.

Comment: I am not that great with Databases but will surely give it a try. And give you an update.

Comment: The performance using the MERGE option degraded to 22-26 sec on Azure [Execution Plan MERGE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fj29gcstilkr5bq/newex11.sqlplan?dl=0) and the Performance with HASH option also was same around 10-13 sec in Azure [Execution Plan HASH](https://www.dropbox.com/s/trp4nnom5riyv2z/New22.sqlplan?dl=0). Removing the Hash and Merge futher degraded the performance.

Comment: @Saurabh, then forget MERGE.  I see that the two left most HASH joins need to spill data to tempdb which is a bad thing. I would remove the two left most HASH while keeping the one that join to customers.

Comment: can you help me optimize this procedure? It would be a great help. [ExecutionPlan](https://ufile.io/2k2dd) . [Stored Procedure](https://ufile.io/uyzs4).

Comment: @Saurabh. Sorry I don't have a computer at hand at this moment, I am on vacancies

Comment: Thanks for replying :) Have fun sorry for disturbing. When you get time do have a look at this [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/213259/need-help-improving-the-stored-procedure-performance/213261?noredirect=1#comment418254_213261)

Answer (score 0):

50 DTU is equivalent to 1/2 logical core.
See more: [Using the Azure SQL Database DTU Calculator](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/tim/using-the-azure-sql-database-dtu-calculator/)

Comment: Oh thanks. :) That's too low. I will explore the DTU calculator and get back soon.

Comment: Also the "Standard" tier and "Premium" tier are graded by DTU but Premium DTUs have solid state storage...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue this week and the final users claimed slowness in using the application connected to the VM hosted in Azure. Also, I have almost the same VM (4CPUs, 14GB of RAM and S3 but with 100DTUs).

In my case, I had a lot of indexes with `avg_fragmentation_in_percent` greater than 30 and this caused poor performance in executing stored procedures.

Run this in SSMS and if the indexes of the tables you are running your stored procedure against are there, then you might take care of it:

```
SELECT dbschemas.[name] as 'Schema',
              dbtables.[name] as 'Table',
              dbindexes.[name] as 'Index',
              indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
              indexstats.page_count
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS indexstats
INNER JOIN sys.tables dbtables on dbtables.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas dbschemas on dbtables.[schema_id] = dbschemas.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS dbindexes ON dbindexes.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
WHERE indexstats.database_id = DB_ID()
AND indexstats.index_id = dbindexes.index_id
AND indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent >30
--AND dbindexes.[name] like '%CLUSTER%'
ORDER BY indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent DESC
```

More info [here](https://support.microsoft.com/ro-ro/help/2755960/sql-query-performance-might-decrease-when-the-sql-server-database-inst).

**Edit:**

Check also how old the statistics are:

```
SELECT 
        sys.objects.name AS table_name,
        sys.indexes.name as index_name, 
        sys.indexes.type_desc as index_type, 
        stats_date(sys.indexes.object_id,sys.indexes.index_id) 
        as last_update_stats_date,
        DATEDIFF(d,stats_date(sys.indexes.object_id,sys.indexes.index_id),getdate()) 
        as stats_age_in_days
FROM  
        sys.indexes
        INNER JOIN sys.objects on sys.indexes.object_id=sys.objects.object_id
WHERE 
        sys.objects.type = 'U' 
        AND
        sys.indexes.index_id > 0 
        --AND sys.indexes.name  Like  '%CLUSTER%'
ORDER BY 
        stats_age_in_days DESC;
GO
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but I did rebuild my Indexes.